# Content DB size increased after RBS migration

Tags: 2013, migration, rbs

I have 500GB content DB.

I migrated data out of SQL Server into RBS but during migration got error after around 15GB data was migrated.

Turns out we need to make some entries in machine.config to fix the issue. I did and started migration again. This time the migration stopped at around 100GB mark.

I made some changes in config file again and restarted migration. This time it went fine but was very very slow and took 6 days to complete.

But now after migration content DB size has increased to 900GB from 500GB. What's going on here?

Comment: When you say the database increased in size, do you mean the transaction log? Since converting to RBS have you since backed up and trimmed the T-logs?